# Create buttons from text file in Javascript

Tags: html, javassist

I am trying to create buttons based on the contents of a text file.  I have pieced together code I found online to almost get the results I want.  I want it to automatically load a predesignated file and create the buttons on page load.  Currently it asks for the user to choose a file. I don't want that, I want it to just load a file with a hard coded name and generate the buttons.

I apologize in advance, I have zero JavaScript experience (please be gentile).

```js
document.getElementById('file').onchange = function () {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    
    reader.onload = function (progressEvent) {
        console.log(this.result);
        
        // Parse file by line
        var lines = this.result.split('\n');
        
        // Create buttons
        for (var line = 0; line < lines.length-1; line++) {
            var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            var t = document.createTextNode(lines[line]);
            
            btn.appendChild(t);
            document.body.appendChild(btn);
        }
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

Answer (score 1):

Web pages are not allowed to read local files from the user's file system without explicit permission. They can however retrieve data from the server they were served from, as well as other servers.

If you're just editing a local web page and don't plan to move it to a server, your computer acts as both the client and the server. So you could use `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `<input type=file>` to access the file you need.

If you're loading your page via `file:///`, you'll need to put your file in the same directory as the web page or in a subdirectory (otherwise the same-origin policy will prevent you from accessing the file).

Comment: @KMCSACK Imagine if you could specify the file to be automatically opened. You just visit a webpage and *bam*, `C:\passwords.txt` is harvested.

Comment: Understood. Changed my code, works perfectly!  Thank you!